# Объясните в чем подвох с запросами?

Tags: yii2

вот запрос

```
$cat= Category::find()->where(['or',['parrent_category'=>0],['parrent_category'=>null]])->all();
var_dump($cat)
```

выдает

```
null
```

иду в дебагер беру от туда запрос к базе данных

```
SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE (`parrent_category`=0) OR (`parrent_category` IS NULL)
```

оформляю его через тот же `phpmyadmin` получаю не меньше 10 значений. Делаю круглые глаза и не понимаю в чем проблема.
Объясните пожалуйста как такое может быть что бы запрос `mysql` выдал 10 значений а запрос `ActiveRecord` ни одного ?

Comment: Возможно запросы шлются на разные серверы/базы

Comment: @vp_arth   ха-ха нет конечно но прикольное предположение. суть в том что если я уберу ['parrent_category'=>null] то нормально выводиться правда без тех категорий у которых "parrent_category" равны  null

Comment: Но вы же достали запрос "из дебаггера"? Т.е. это именно тот запрос, который php слал в базу?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить этот массив на строку `parrent_category is null`

Comment: @vp_arth да вы не обижайтесь пожалуйста я просто ситуацию прикинул. А с `parrent_category is null` эффект тот же запрос как надо но вот ответа нет.

Comment: @vp_arth надо за раскладкой наблюдать русская c

Comment: Это всё из-за копипастофобии =)

Comment: @vp_arth :) где то читал что код лучше самому писать ручками так сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Если запросы одинаковые, значит где-то после запроса есть логика, которая влияет. В Yii2 AR есть события, например afterFind в котором, может быть логика.
Проверьте если вместо `->all();` сделать `->count();` и проверьте методы модели, подключенные поведения и т.д. Можете показать код модели?